# Django Rest Framework unable to parse multipart/form data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rest

As stated in DRF documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser, in order to parse multipart/form-data, the MultiPart and form parser must be used. I have a supiscion this is a problem in the Django Rest Framework because I saw a solution on their github issue saying it work using APIView.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from api.serializers import UserSerializer,

from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Picture of me sending request to Postman with result:
[image: Picture of me sending request to Postman with result]

Edit: Adding UserSerializer class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snapcapsules = SnapCapsuleSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        allow_null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('snapcapsules', 'url', 'username', 'email', 'password', )
        write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        capsules_data = validated_data.pop('snapcapsules')

        for capsule in capsules_data:
             SnapCapsule.objects.create(user=instance, **capsule)

        return instance
```

[image: Picture of what I of what I requested]

Comment: Show `UserSerializer` please.

Comment: cat u post the post body, because if u set request header multipart/form-data,u can just post data with the postman form-data rather than x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. You've set the header to multipart/forn-data, but then what you're actually sending is clearly JSON and not form data at all.

Comment: @WaketZheng I posted the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is might not the issue with the `ContentType`. The error response says that,the  `UserSerializer` excpect a `payload`or`data` which **include `username` and `password` field**
So, Please try to add those fields to the **request body** and try again
[image: POstman ScreenShot]

## UPDATE

The problem with the [Orginal Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50959137/8283848) was, he added extra headers in POSTMAN (see the pic below)
 [image].
**Postman will add appropriate Headers aromatically for you. So, you don't have to explicitly mention it**

Comment: Yes, I had something in the Post Body, but I forgot to add the picture. You can see what I sent with the results above now.

Comment: Well, then I recommend you to **open a new POSTMAN tab and repeat the procedure and also do not manually  provide anything on `Headers`  tab**

Comment: Postman will add appropriate Headers aromatically for you. So, you don't have to explicitly mention it

Answer (score 2):

I removed one line and then it worked!

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Also, the serializer can be rewrite as follows:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            password=validated_data['password']
        )

    ...
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not work. Are you using the multipart parser because the documentations say you need to in order to process multipart/form-data.

Comment: When I change my headers to empty, your solutions works. I upvoted your for this reason. Thank you.