# Update User REST framework Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I need to update my user in **REST framework**

**views.py**

```
class UserUpdate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self,request):
        user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        try:
            user_serializer=UserSerializer(request.user,data=request.data, partial=True)
            if user_serializer.is_valid():
                user_serializer.save()
                return Response(user_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'status':0,'message':'Error on user update'})
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar']
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    fb_userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
```

response:
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.

[image]

Comment: Show us your full view class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   def post(self,request):
        user_serializer=UserSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
            return Response(user_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: { "id": 2, "first_name": "", "last_name": "", "avatar": null }  please check postman image

Comment: The url you are asking is update_user,is this url connect to this posyt method?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to post data with this url

Comment: but you still get user unchanged? can you `print(request.data, user_serializer.validated_data)`  inside  `if user_serializer.is_valid()`  and post it to question

Comment: <QueryDict: {' name': ['"first_name"\r\n\r\nTarun\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryeZV6EJv4GBVHzMQS--\r\n'], '------WebKitFormBoundaryeZV6EJv4GBVHzMQS\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data': ['']}>

Comment: The code is right,there must be some mistake in the data you post.

Answer (score 1):

@YKH is right this code is good there may error in your POST data.

In your image, you are passing two parameters in **Header**. It could possible you are passing the wrong header.
**Content-Type** should not be for form-data

Answer (score 1):

I found this post where someone has a similar problem as you: [Django Rest Framework unable to parse multipart/form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959137/django-rest-framework-unable-to-parse-multipart-form-data)

It seems on your picture that you are putting something into Headers tab.  Postman is taking care of that for you, so you shouldn't define anything there. Could you try again without setting anything in the headers?